# Criando e usando componente no angular 2

Tags: angular

Criei este componente para mostrar mensagem de sucesso ou não.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-snack-bar',
  templateUrl: './snack-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snack-bar.component.css']
})
export class SnackBarComponent {

  snackBar: MatSnackBar

  constructor(

  ) {}

  openSnackBar(message: string, isOnline : boolean) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, undefined, 
      { duration: 3000, 
        panelClass: isOnline ? ["online", "onlineAction"] : "offline" }
      );
  }
}
```

Para chamar estou fazendo assim:

```
onSubmit(form){
    const snackBarComponent = SnackBarComponent;
    snackBarComponent.prototype.openSnackBar(dados.mensagem, true);
}
```

Só que apresenta este erro no console do navegador:

> ```
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
>         at Object.SnackBarComponent.openSnackBar (snack-bar.component.ts:18)
>         at MunicipioFormComponent.onSubmit (municipio-form.component.ts:115)
>         at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (MunicipioFormComponent.html:1)
>         at handleEvent (core.js:13547)
>         at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
>         at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14643)
>         at dispatchEvent (core.js:9962)
>         at eval (core.js:12301)
>         at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:4343)
>         at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:243)
>     View_MunicipioFormComponent_0 @ MunicipioFormComponent.html:1
>     proxyClass @ compiler.js:14653
>     DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:14996
>     ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1509
>     dispatchEvent @ core.js:9966
>     (anonymous) @ core.js:12301
>     schedulerFn @ core.js:4343
>     SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:243
>     SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:190
>     Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:131
>     Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:95
>     Subject.next @ Subject.js:56
>     EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:4311
>     NgForm.onSubmit @ forms.js:5762
>     (anonymous) @ MunicipioFormComponent.html:1
>     handleEvent @ core.js:13547
>     callWithDebugContext @ core.js:15056
>     debugHandleEvent @ core.js:14643
>     dispatchEvent @ core.js:9962
>     (anonymous) @ core.js:10587
>     (anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:2628
>     ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
>     onInvokeTask @ core.js:4740
>     ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
>     Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
>     ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
>     invokeTask @ zone.js:1517
>     globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1543
>     MunicipioFormComponent.html:1 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
> ```

O que pode ser ?

Comment: Para chamar não seria assim: `snackBarComponent.openSnackBar(dados.mensagem, true);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Você não esta inicializando o snackBar, você tem que por ele no construtor por angular injetar ele.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-snack-bar',
  templateUrl: './snack-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snack-bar.component.css']
})
export class SnackBarComponent {     

  constructor(
      private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
      private messageService: MessageService
  ) {
  this.message.getMessages().subscribe(message=>this.openSnackBar(message.message, message.isOnline ))
}

  openSnackBar(message: string, isOnline : boolean) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, undefined, 
      { duration: 3000, 
        panelClass: isOnline ? ["online", "onlineAction"] : "offline" }
      );
  }
}
```

**message.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService{
    private messageSubject= new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {}

    addMessage(message) {
        this.messageSubject.next(message);
    }

    getMessages(): Observable<any> {
        return this.messageSubject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim, fiz o que você disse. Não ocorreu erro pois, entendo que não chamei este componente.

Como chamo ?

Se faço isto, dá o mesmo erro.

const snackBarComponent = SnackBarComponent;
    snackBarComponent.prototype.openSnackBar(dados.mensagem, true);

Entendeu ?

Comment: Voce quer chamar do mesmo componente? Se sim você pode chamar assim: this.openSnackBar(dados.mensagem, true);

Comment: Não.

Exemplo. Existe os componentes: Bairro, BairroBusca, Estado, EstadoBusca, entre outros, mais de 50.

A idéia é criar este componente e chamar nos formulários passando os parametros quando necessário.

Entendeu ?

Comment: nesse case você precisa criar um serviço que você injeta nos outros components com um behavior subject que você recebe os parâmetros ai você mostra quando necessário. Vou editar minha resposta pra te dar uma ideia.

Comment: Ai para chamar no Bairro, seria assim: 

No construtor, coloco assim:

private messageService : MessageService;

ai na execução assim:

messageService.addMessage("minha mensagem");

Correto ?

Comment: tipo isso ou entao vc pode fazer um objeto com a mensagem e o booleano ou um array vai de vc.

Comment: O certo seria criar uma interface export interface Message {message:string, isOnline:boolean}

Comment: ai coloca la addMessage(message:Message)

Comment: Blz. Vou tentar solucionar aqui e coloco o resultado. De qualquer forma obrigado.